# export excel with image inside the file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, excel

i am tring to make a web
im using php and jquery
ive using this code to make a function to save export my data to excel:

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function(table, name) {
if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
})()
```

but it appear that with this code, i can not export image to the excel file too. 
the code only give the location of the image file, but did not bring the image with it
hope i can get any answer.

thanks, hope get some answer for it.

here what my works look link [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsO1c.png) and this is what looks like in excel [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Rf3.png)

Comment: What exactly is going on here? That's some seriously unreadable code even by JavaScript standards.

Comment: its a jquery that my friend give me to use,it works. but we absolutely didnt know how to modify it to make it can also bring image file with it. not just the location. here what my works look link [link](http://i.imgur.com/SduSu8N.png) and this is what looks like in excel [link](http://i.imgur.com/xGXZ9om.png)